# Botium - Google Assistant Connector - Error empty response while response ins't empty

Tags: automated-tests, bots, actions-on-google

I am using botium box and configured a Google Assistant Connector.
When I run a test case, I encounter the following botium core error :

```
Empty response, configuration, or start utterance Parler avec test app name invalid :
{ 
  micOpen: true,
  textToSpeech: [],
  displayText: [],
  ssml:
   [ "<speak><s>In order to purchase a product, please contact our support.</s><s>Can I do anything else for you ?</s></speak>" ],
  suggestions: [] 
}
```

However, as you can see, the response is not empty as it contains my actions' answer in the ssml array and since my actions answers correctly the start utterance seems correct.

Any idea on why botium core considers this answer to be an error ?

Thanks !

Comment: can you pls attach the full logfile output from verbose mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Botium Google Assistant Connector](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-google-assistant) currently only supports the "textToSpeech" element. There are some amendments planned for december release, the SSML support will be one of them.